# Angular JavaScript filter function, updating with $scope input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently writing a little function to take a $scope value from an input field, then add it to a new array containing invited users.

To prevent duplicate entries into the array I'm trying to use JavaScript's filter method.

My problem is when I look at whats being output to the console, the console.log inside the filter function always prints the same Email value, it doesn't seem to update and consider the new input. e.g. a user has added 2 users, the first will be added and the invitesArr will only contain the first Email.

```
        var invitesArr = $scope.invites;
        console.log(invitesArr)
        console.log($scope.searchContacts)

        if ($scope.invites.length >= 0) {
            invitesArr.filter(function(invitesArr) {
                console.log(invitesArr.Email)
                return invitesArr.Email === $scope.searchContacts;
            });

            if (invitesArr == false) {
                courseAccountService.inviteGuestToCourse($scope.courseId,$scope.searchContacts).
                then(function(invitation) {
                    $scope.invites.push(invitation);
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using same variable **invitesArr** for array, inside filter function and boolean condition

Comment: Not really, I just need to check if the Email value has a value that matches one from the original array. E.g if $scope.invites contains x, then I need to check if the new $scope.searchContacts matches x

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var invitesArr = $scope.invites;
    console.log(invitesArr)
    console.log($scope.searchContacts)

    if ($scope.invites.length >= 0) {
       //use arrow operator instead of function.
       var duplicateEmails = invitesArr.filter((item) => {
            console.log(invitesArr.Email)
            //assuming datatype of item.Email and $scope.searchContacts are same else use == for comparision
            return item.Email === $scope.searchContacts; 
        });

        //Check for length and then push to your invites
        if (duplicateEmails.length==0) {
            courseAccountService.inviteGuestToCourse($scope.courseId,$scope.searchContacts).
            then(function(invitation) {
                $scope.invites.push(invitation);
            });
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!!